# onTimeUpdate Linked to Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've been working at this for a few days now, trying to take the basics from another JsFiddle and incorporate it into my own. I'm trying to make a music player, but am having trouble using the `ontimeUpdate` function in JavaScript. This is the function that I'm working with at the moment:

```
audio.on("timeupdate", function() {
   $("#bar").attr("value", this.currentTime / this.duration);
});
```

where `audio` is a variable representing the `<audio>` element, and `#bar` is the id of a `<progress>` element. Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4t2tf0af/5/

And here is the fiddle I'm working from: http://jsfiddle.net/DCE6N/547/

Now, in the latter fiddle, when music plays, the progress bar updates to the decimal value of between 0 and 1. I'm trying to do the same with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed a few issues, but to answer your first question, "audio" is a dom element so it doesn't have anything called "on". So you need to wrap it in jquery tags for on to work:

```
  $(audio).on("timeupdate", function()
  {
    $("#bar").attr("value", (this.currentTime / this.duration) * 100);
  });
```

You'll notice that I also multiplied the value by 100, because while the original fiddle had "1" as the max, yours had "100" as the maximum.

There were a few characters at the end of the fiddle that were preventing it from working as well.

Finally, you needed to set the protocol for the song you were accessing to https:

```
audio.setAttribute("src", "https://mp3red.co/stream/27942256/wintersleep-amerika.mp3"
```

Here's an updated fiddle that I've tweaked that you can try:

https://jsfiddle.net/4t2tf0af/8/